# How is manipulation of derivatives possible?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In parametric differentiation, finding the second derivative can be given by:

- $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx}) = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dt}*\frac{dt}{dx})$

Now if I am differentiating two functions multiplied together, I would use the product rule right?

- $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dt}*\frac{dt}{dx})$ = $\frac{dt}{dx}*\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dt})$ + $\frac{dy}{dt}* \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dt}{dx})$

But that is a wrong manipulation, rather this is what is given in my textbook:

[image]

Manipulating derivatives is hard, at some points, they act like fractions, while at others they do not. How do I know for sure that what I am doing is correct?

Comment: When you write an equation in Mathjax, start with the `$` (or `$$`), then write the **entire equation**, then the `$` (or `$$`) to end the equation. It's designed to format the $=$ and $+$ signs nicely too, not just the fractions.

Comment: Is the star operator above meant to be multiplication or convolution or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation commonly used for higher-order derivatives SHOULD NOT be used as fractions.  In order to treat higher-order derivatives as fractions, the notation needs to be derived from the quotient rule.  For instance, if you want to be able to manipulate the differentials as a fraction, the notation for the second derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ should be:

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$$

You can find that by using the quotient rule on $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and simplifying.

More information about this notation can be found in a paper I wrote titled "[Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials](https://www.academia.edu/37619039/Extending_the_Algebraic_Manipulability_of_Differentials)".  The standard notation is suggestive only, and cannot be manipulated as if it were a quotient of actual terms.

Now, we can find the answer to this particular problem without diving too deep into new notation.  A good halfway point is to treat $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\text{expression}\right)$ as actually being $\frac{d(\text{expression})}{dx}$.  So, given that, we can rewrite the formula like this:

$$\frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dx} = \frac{d\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{dt} \times \frac{dt}{dx} $$

Since these are all first order differentials, the terms can cancel, and it is clear why the equivalency exists.

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think your first formula was wrong?

For example, let $t = \cos x,$ and let $y = t^2 = \cos^2 x.$ Then

\begin{align}
\frac{dt}{dx} &= -\sin x, \\
\frac{dy}{dt} &= 2t = 2\cos x, \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= - 2 \sin x\cos x, \\
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} &= 2 \sin^2 x - 2 \cos^2 x.
\end{align}

Now you can write
$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx}$ by the chain rule,
and then (as you wrote) the product rule indeed says

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)
&= \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx}\right) \\
&= \frac{dt}{dx} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)
  + \frac{dy}{dt} \cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right) \\
&= \left(-\sin x\right) \frac{d}{dx}\left(2\cos x\right)
  + \left(2\cos x\right) \frac{d}{dx}\left(-\sin x\right) \\
&= \left(-\sin x\right) \left(- 2 \sin x\right)
  + \left(2\cos x\right) \left(-\cos x\right) \\
&=  2 \sin^2 x - 2\cos^2 x,
\end{align}
which is the correct result.

What the textbook is doing, on the other hand, is applying the chain rule to the **outermost** derivative instead of the **innermost** derivative. That is, they say
$$ \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{du}{dt} \cdot \frac{dt}{dx} $$
where
$$ u = \frac{dy}{dx}. $$
That's all. It is a simple formula derived by a simple method.
But the fact that there is such a simple formula for rewriting a second derivative does not mean that every other rewriting of the second derivative is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you did and what the textbook did are both right, it's just that you used the chain rule on the inner $\frac{d}{dx}$ to write it as $\frac{dt}{dx}\frac{d}{dt}$, and the textbook used it on the outer $\frac{d}{dx}$, (ie. when writing $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}y$)